# Incorrect/undesirable ogv MIME type from PHP fileinfo

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, mime-types, responsive-filemanager

I tried this on most of the servers I have, and PHP seems to return `application/ogg` for ogv video files. This is strange, because the Apache mime config file clearly lists `video/ogg` (also not desirable, but at least it would make sense since the info is supposed to be coming from there). Originally I encountered this problem in Responsive File Manager, but was able to reproduce it independently.

The code:

```
$fileinfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime_type = finfo_file($fileinfo, $file);
finfo_close($fileinfo);

var_dump($mime_type);
```

The output:

```
string(31) "application/ogg; charset=binary"
```

Where is this information coming from, and how can I change it?

Putting .htaccess directives doesn't seem to help at all. It probably also matters that I am running cPanel/WHM, but wasn't able to find any additional relevant configuration. Moreover, cPanel also gives `video/ogg` for ogv, just like Apache.

Comment: It is not possible to know what an Ogg container actually contains without deeper analysis than is being performed here.

Comment: That's good to know. I will be satisfied with information on how to force PHP to return the MIME type I want for ogv though—preferably without making changes to the RFM code. Even understanding where PHP fetched this type from (directly from the file header? That seems unlikely, but possible) might allow me to force it to work with .htaccess instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `finfo_file` is using the Linux `file` command: https://linux.die.net/man/1/file

Output of `finfo_file`:

```
application/ogg; charset=binary
```

Output of `file -i sample.ogv`

```
application/ogg; charset=binary
```

One solution is to use `apache_lookup_uri` which sounds like it may work for you since you're running on Apache: http://php.net/apache_lookup_uri

```
var_dump( apache_lookup_uri('sample.ogv') );

object(stdClass)#1 (16) {
  ["status"]=>
  int(200)
  ["the_request"]=>
  string(27) "GET /tmp/test.php HTTP/1.1"
  ["method"]=>
  string(3) "GET"
  ["mtime"]=>
  int(0)
  ["clength"]=>
  int(0)
  ["chunked"]=>
  int(0)
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(9) "video/ogg"
  ["no_cache"]=>
  int(0)
  ["no_local_copy"]=>
  int(1)
  ["unparsed_uri"]=>
  string(16) "/mime/sample.ogv"
  ["uri"]=>
  string(16) "/mime/sample.ogv"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(48) "/tmp/sample.ogv"
  ["allowed"]=>
  int(0)
  ["sent_bodyct"]=>
  int(0)
  ["bytes_sent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_time"]=>
  int(1504107700)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For the record: using apache_lookup_uri didn't work, and eventually I had to modify the Responsive FileManager code to work around this problem. Hopefully it will work for someone else though.